# How can I avoid my expression type NSDictionary being "too ambiguous"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, xcode11

I am setting up a search mechanism for my app, and I am receiving the error "Expression type 'NSDictionary' is ambiguous without more context". I've looked this up, and can't find any answers for my particular case. I'm pretty stuck, and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
var usersArray = [NSDictionary?]()
var filteredUsers = [NSDictionary?]()

let db = Firestore.firestore()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    db.collection("users").order(by: "username").getDocuments()
        { (snapshot, error) in
                self.usersArray.append(snapshot.value as? NSDictionary?)

                self.findUsersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
    }

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don’t use `NSDictionary` with Swift.

Comment: What do you think I should use instead?

Comment: You should use Swift dictionaries; something like `[String:Any]`. Also an array of optional dictionaries doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: So how would that work in this example? Do I just replace references to NSDictionary with Dictionary ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change couple of things here :

```
if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

guard let snapshot = snapshot,
      let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {                  
          return
}

usersArray.append(snapshotValue)
self.findUsersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
```

as @Paulw11 suggested and I quote: "Don't use `NSDictionary` in `swift`". So your array need to be like this:

```
var usersArray: [[String: Any]] = []
```

Now on the `Firestore` part, Please refer below URL, or the official firestore documentation as you are not using it correctly:

- http://fabcoding.com/cloud-firestore-for-ios/